# How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webmatrix

How to import a namespace in Razor View Page?

Comment: You can also add alias to your imported namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798293/mvc3-import-namespace/8043480#8043480

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Import-a-Namespace-in-Razor-View-Page-with-example

Answer (score 897, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

```
@using MyNamespace
```

For VB.Net:

```
@Imports Mynamespace
```

Take a look at [@ravy amiry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723046/5519709) if you want to include a namespace across the app.

Comment: Also:  They can't go in code blocks.  (You'll get a runtime error)

Comment: Also you don't need the semicolon.

Comment: hi, how to use globalization in view in mvc, as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744037/2218697) ?

Comment: This is just bad practice period.  Please do not add this to the top of your razor pages.  This is messy etc...    Correct way is to add to Views - web.config just as @Javad_Amiry points out.

Comment: It's not bad practice.  It's an absolutely necessary feature.  web.config is like a global using statement that makes the namespace active in ALL your pages.  That may not be what you want if you have classes with the same name in different namespaces.  You'll still have a conflict if you try to use them in the same file, but you can resolve that easily within a single file.  If you stick it in web.config, then the conflict would arise in all your pages that use either of the classes.  So calling this bad practice makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm surprised Intellisense doesn't hint to add the using statement the same way it does in normal C# pages.

Comment: @Triynko It may not be a _bad_ practice, based on the valid examples you provided, however without those conflicts, this definitely isn't the _best_ practice.

Comment: What if it's narrowed down to not using Imports Mynamespace at all and only use it within the view where necessary?  For example, If Mynamespace.objClass Then... without Imports, instead of If objClass Then.... with Imports.Mynamespace.

Answer (score 415):

The first way is that use `@using` statement in `.cshtml` files, that imports a namespace to current file only, and the second:

**In the "web.config" file in "`Views`" directory of your project (notice it is *not* the main web.config in project's root)**, find this section:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      .
      .
      <!-- etc -->
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

you can add your custom namespace like this:

```
<add namespace="My.Custom" />
```

that will add the namespace to all of .cshtml (and/or .vbhtml) files;
also you can change views inheritance from here, like:

```
<pages pageBaseType="My.Custom.MyWebViewPage">
```

Regards.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @`Nick Silberstein` to his reminder about areas! He said:

*If you're working within an **area**, you must add the `namespace` within the `Web.config` under `/Areas/<AreaName>/Views/` rather than
`/Views/`*

Comment: I don't have that section in my web.config, should I add it?

Comment: @vtortola : which web.config? the web.config file in Views folder, not the main web.config in root folder. ok?

Comment: I'd like to hopefully save someone a few minutes of pulling out their hair and say that if you're working within an area, you must add the namespace within the Web.config under /Areas/<AreaName>Views/ rather than /Views/.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels No it does not need to restart VS. Just build the project and it will take effect. At least I do this always. If a view is open, you have to close that view before build and re-open it after after build.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry, aha, I did rebuild, but didn't close the view.

Comment: Using the web.config method of importing prevents polluting views with too many implementation details, like which implementation of a class to use.  This assumes two implementations would share the same name but have different namespaces.  You could shoehorn in a test-only implementation by using web.config transformations, and a `blah.blah.test` namespace.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way.  Not the Using statement at top of Razor page like in the OP selected answer....

Comment: Regardless of what Microsoft intended, I consider coding through config files a bad practice -- configs should be for system 'where do I find stuff', or simple parameter changes.  I'm surprised that xxx.models and xxx.controllers -- etc doesn't just work, since MVC is based on that kind of magic configuration.

Answer (score 34):

For Library

```
@using MyNamespace
```

For Model

```
@model MyModel
```

Comment: Why is there no ; at the end?

Comment: @FrenkyB because this isn't C# code, it's Razor code. The `using` at the beginning of a .cs file is a C# compiler keyword. The `@using` at the beginning of a .cshtml file is a hint to the Razor template engine.

Answer (score 27):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview1 you can import a namespace on all your razor views with this code in Global.asax.cs

```
Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation.CodeGeneratorSettings.AddGlobalImport("Namespace.Namespace");
```

I hope in RTM this gets done through Web.config  section.

Comment: There will be a web.config section in RTM, but we also wanted to provide an API to do this because many users are starting to gravitate away from config.  So we have both options available for you!

Comment: As of ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta this method no longer works. There is a new web.config section as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/razor-syntax-using-and-namespace-declarations-fail . The AddGlobalImport method for importing a global namespace to all views has been moved to this class System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPagesRazorHost

Answer (score 16):

I found this http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/07/30/add-namespaces-with-razor.aspx which explains how to add a custom namespace to all your razor pages.

Basically you can make this

```
using Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation;
public class PreApplicationStart
{
   public static void InitializeApplication()
   {
       CodeGeneratorSettings.AddGlobalImport("Custom.Namespace");
   }
}
```

and put the following code in your AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStart), "InitializeApplication")]
```

the method InitializeApplication will be executed before Application_Start in global.asax

Comment: This is actually a rather good answer, but the location of `Microsoft.WebPages.Compilation.AddGlobalImport` was changed to `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebCodeRazorHost.AddGlobalImport`.

Comment: The big advantage of using this method comes from the fact that the namespace will be usable in all views (including those within areas) while being declared in just one place.

Answer (score 14):

One issue that you must know is that when you import a namespace via `web.config` in `Views` folder, that `namespace` is imported **JUST** for views in that **folder**. Means if you want to import a `namespace` in an **area views**, you must also import that `namespace`, in that area's `web.config` file, located in area's `Views` folder;

Answer (score 12):

For namespace and Library

```
@using NameSpace_Name
```

For Model

```
@model Application_Name.Models.Model_Name
```

For Iterate the list on Razor Page (You Have to use foreach loop for access the list items)

```
@model List<Application_Name.Models.Model_Name>

@foreach (var item in Model)
   {  
          <tr>
                <td>@item.srno</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
         </tr>  
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
@using MyNamespace
```

Answer (score 3):

"using MyNamespace" works in MVC3 RTM. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think in order import namespace in razor view, you just need to add below way:

```
@using XX.YY.ZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your need you can use one of following method:

- In first line/s of view add "using your.domainName;" (if it is
  required in specific view only)
- if required in all subsequent views
  then add "using your.domainName;" in _ViewStart.cshtml. You can find
  more about this in: [Where and how is the _ViewStart.cshtml layout file linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300410/where-and-how-is-the-viewstart-cshtml-layout-file-linked)
- Or add Assembly reference in View web.config as described by others explained in: [How do you implement a @using across all Views in Asp.Net MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142540/how-do-you-implement-a-using-across-all-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3/8142559)

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can do it in the following ways

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;