# External References not referenced in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reference, razor

I am working with MVC3 with razor view.
I am trying to use a model from different project than the mvc3 project,
for same its report compilation error as

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyNameSpace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

as answered in some [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953330/razor-based-view-doesnt-see-referenced-assemblies), I tried to add @using directive or editing web.config in Views folder, but it is still not working.

Could somebody please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing a assembly to my project. Seems adding the reference wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, adding the reference wouldn't be enough. It needs to be added as an assembly to the project, or the compiler won't be able to find the library.