# models in separate assembly from asp.net mvc4 web project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, assemblies

I have a solution with the following projects:

- **App.Web.Private** - Administration web interface.
- **App.Web.Public** - End-user public interface.
- **App.Web.Core** - Commons for both private and public interfaces.

I would like to know how can I separate my models from *public* and *private* web interfaces and put them into *App.Web.Core*?

I tried adding the namespaces in web.config, but seems not to work correctly, I always get a *missing assembly reference*...

### Update

Note: both *private* and *public* interface are referencing *App.Web.Core*. The question is related to this strange behavior although the references are done but the project can't see it. As I mentioned on the original question, I also added the references in both web.config.

### Update 2

This is a screenshot of the error:
[image: error]

Comment: That's a pretty self-explanatory error message: you moved the models to the other project, so the project that's trying to *use* the models needs a reference to that assembly that *contains* the models.

Comment: I understood the message, the problem is that the project where the models are is already referenced...

Comment: So, is this a compile time error, or a runtime error?

Comment: It is are runtime error.

Comment: I assume you are getting a Yellow screen error message on this, would it be possible to let us see that message?

Comment: @scott-pascoe, screenshot added.

Comment: Try adding, in the razor view an @Using ...models at the top. This should validate that you've got the right physical stuff arranged.  If it succeeds, then I would go back and look at the added reference in the web.config and make sure it doesn't have a typo.

Comment: I added the `@using`, but the problem persist. The autocomplete, let me reference the namespace from the external assembly, but the runtime exception still the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24386/discussion-between-scott-pascoe-and-rubens-mariuzzo)

Comment: Please post your the namespace section of your `~/web.config` and `~/Views/web.config`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `@using App.Web.Core` to the top of the view.  If that works, then you'll know you've got the physical stuff right.  Then go check for typos.

Comment: What a shame! My model name is `Foo` and I put `Foos`... bad me...

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, right click referenced, add App.Web.Core

Comment: Thanks, I have update my original question, because that's not my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010:

- Right click on "References" and click on "Add Reference...".
- Choose the App.Web.Core project and click "Ok".

Now when you want to use these models from App.Web.Core you also need to add an using statement at the top of your class.

Example: `using App.Web.Core.Models;`

Comment: Thanks, but I have hundreds of razor files... and I already have other references (from same assembly of the web project) in web.config that I can use without writing `using`.

Comment: Maybe this is something you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953330/razor-based-view-doesnt-see-referenced-assemblies

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of .Net against which the Public and Private project have been build. Project Core may be on an older version of .Net and Public and Private on a new.

To check the version open project properties page and verify.