# Referencing type that is in another assembly causes "the type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" error in Razor.Compile()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

We are currently using the Razor View engine to render out HTML (outside of an ASP.NET MVC project). Everything has been working okay until today when I added an enum type to my model that resides in another assembly. Now when I compile, I get the following error:

> "RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Unable to compile template. The type
>   'ClassLibrary1.MyClass.MyEnum' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ClassLibrary1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

I was able to reproduce this error in a simply console application that references a type from an external DLL:

Template:

```
@model RazorExample.MyModel  

<div>  
    @if(Model.EnumValue == ExternalLib.MyEnum.Val1) { <p>My value is 1</p> }  
</div>
```

Enum (defined in ExternalLib):

```
namespace ExternalLib   
{  
    public enum MyEnum  
    {  
        Val1 = 1,  
        Val2 = 2  
    }  
}
```

Model:

```
using ExternalLib;  

namespace RazorExample  
{  
    public class MyModel  
    {  
        public String Name { get; set; }  
        public MyEnum EnumValue{ get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

Code to compile the template:

```
Razor.Compile(template.ToString(), "MyTemplate");
```

I have also tried adding a "@using ExtneralLib;" to the template but that results in an error that the type "ExternalLib" could not be found. I have seen one or two other posts regarding something similar ([Razor-based view doesn't see referenced assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953330/razor-based-view-doesnt-see-referenced-assemblies)) but this is not in the context of a web application. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I spoke a little too soon that this fixed my error yesterday. It fixed my error in my test app but when I went to update my code, it did not work. After looking at it a bit more, I realized my model was a little more complicated.

I have updated my sample app accordingly:

**Model:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ParentClass ParentClass { get; set; }
}
```

**ParentClass:**

```
namespace ExternalLib
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ChildClass ChildClass { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ChildClass:**

```
namespace ExternalLib
{
    public class ChildClass
    {
        public enum MyEnum
        {
            Val1 = 1,
            Val2 = 2
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
@model RazorExample.MyModel
<div>
    @if(Model.ParentClass.ChildClass.EnumValue == ExternalLib.ChildClass.MyEnum.Val1) { <p>My value is 1</p> }  
</div>
```

With this code, if I add the @using ExternalLib; statement into the model, I get the error "Unable to compile template. The type or namespace name 'ExternalLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

If I leave the @using statement out, I get the exception "Unable to compile template. The type 'ExternalLib.ParentClass' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ExternalLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

**FIX (or workaround at least)**
I was able to fix this in the code I am trying to get working by creating a separate model and template for the child class and using an @Include statement in the template to import it in. I can post that code if anyone is interested but I fear I am already a little long on the post.

Comment: Obvious question: Did you actually right click on your Project in the solution explorer and `Add Reference...` to ClassLibrary1?

Comment: Same question as @Eris...also, you will still need a `using` reference at top of view

Comment: I did add the reference. Also, I tried adding a @using statement but with no luck. Rich's answer below (#1) fixed my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code:

1: You need to specify the type of your model object when calling `Razor.Compile(...)`:

```
Razor.Compile(template.ToString(), typeof(MyModel), "MyTemplate");
```

2: Your template checks the value of `ExternalLib.MyEnum == ExternalLib.MyEnum.Val1` but your model's enum value property is `MyNestedEnum`, not `MyEnum`.

Change your template to the following:

```
@model RazorExample.MyModel  

<div>  
    @if(Model.MyNestedEnum == ExternalLib.MyEnum.Val1) { <p>My value is 1</p> }  
</div>
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Rich - #2 on your list was a missed change on my part when trying to clarify the code. #1 on your list worked for me, thanks a bunch!