# Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, compiler-errors

So, this error appears when I try to get a `Razor` view compiled.

The source is the Line 28 of the `Web.config` file inside the `Views` folder:

```
Line 26:     using System.Web.Optimization;
Line 27:     using System.Web.Routing;
Line 28:     using RuleRegressionTesterLib; //here
Line 29:     using RuleRegressionTesterWebSite;
```

Here are the `References`:

[image]

`Configuration Manager...`

[image]

Here is the `view`:

```
@using RuleRegressionTesterLib.Results
@model IEnumerable<ReportResult>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
```

Here is the `Web.config` file inside the `Views` folder (as recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953343/1188208) answer)

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="RuleRegressionTesterLib" />
        <add namespace="RuleRegressionTesterWebSite" />
    </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Why is this happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, but I had to actually add the assembly to the `Views/web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="RuleRegressionTesterLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Does anybody know why?