# Razor View Errors When System.Web.Mvc Version Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The same ASP.NET MVC project pulled from GitHub compiles without any errors in my friend's PC but in mine, only in Razor View files (.cshtml) I get multiple errors like:

```
The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context
```

Since I thought it was regarding config files I deleted and cloned the project but still the same. The project will run fine though. But because of this problem I cannot get proper IntelliSense in development.

---

Update:

For some weird reason if I change `System.Web.Mvc` version to `5.0.0.0` in my PC then errors in View go away.

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

But why?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: [The name viewbag does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960148/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context) ?

Comment: If there is a problem with `web.config` then it should not work on my friend's PC either.

Comment: try to restart the visual studio, delete `.user` or `.suo` file, and rebuild

Comment: @YuliamChandra There is `.user` file and deleting `.suo` and rebuilding did not work.

Comment: It is a `web.config` error or the target framework is wrong. Right click your project's properties, change the target framework to whichever it should be.

Comment: I mentioned that everything between my friend's PC and mine are exactly the same.