# ASP.NET MVC View is failing to compile

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Version = 1;
    ViewBag.Debug = false;
}
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

> [ERROR] The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context (@ line 2)
>
> [ERROR] The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context (@ line 3)
>
> [WARNING] ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies.

I have installed the latest version of ASP.NET MVC (5.2.3) via NuGet.

[image: Project references]

As you can see, `System.Web.Helpers` is referenced.

Also, I have the following page namespaces in my `Views/Web.config`:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
         </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Why can't I locate the `ViewBag` property and why does that warning shows up?

### UPDATE

Using `ViewContext.ViewBag` instead of just `ViewBag` seems to compile and work. But why is this happening?

Comment: This might be a stupid comment, but have you tried a clean/rebuild?  And are the DLLs in your bin folder for the dependencies?

Comment: @Coulton Yep, like six times already. Not a stupid comment at all, I checked other questions and rebuilding seemed to solve the issue. It didn't work for me, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960148/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: When I've had issues like this, I'm sure that doing an update on Manage Nuget Dependencies fixed this for me.  I don't know if that's an option to you just to test.

Comment: @Duston Yes, it seems my Web.config contains all it needs to have, but the problem persists

Comment: @Coulton Where is this `Manager Nuget Dependencies` button? If you mean `Manage Nuget Packages`, then I already tried. All my packages are up-to-date.

Comment: Yes that's the one I mean :).  If they're up to date then it's not really an option.  It's like you need to refresh all of your NuGet packages.

Comment: Perhaps running `Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>` on the related packages could help? or deleting the DLLs from the packages folder and rebuilding your app?  Short of that I'm at a loss, I'll have to leave it to others.

Comment: @Coulton Ran that command with `<packageName>` equals to `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` but still no luck :(

Comment: Check the properties of your application for the bin location and confirm that the DLLs required are in that folder after the build.

Comment: @Coulton `System.Web.Mvc.dll` and `System.Web.Helpers.dll` are in that folder along with ~5 more DLLs that must be the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Which versions of the assemblies do you currently have?

According to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3
Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 has the following dependencies:

```
    Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)
```

And according to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/
ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 3.2.3  has the following dependencies:

```
    Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)
    Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)
```

Perhaps nuget did not pull all the required versions.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers/. I don't need that package, that is just a helper library for adding new features to a website, it has nothing to do with `System.Web.Helpers`

Comment: You are right, that assembly is not related. Regarding System.Web.Helpers I found the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor  perhaps you need to change target framework from '.NET framework 4 client profile' to '.NET framework 4'?

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove MVC assemblies
2. Get right version of MVC assemblies like  C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll.