# Error in ASP.Net MVC5 layout page - 'viewbag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, viewbag

My other razor view pages have `@ViewBag.Something`, and those are not creating any problem.

But I have added a layout page in the shared directory, which contains `@ViewBag.Something`.

Now I am getting -

> 'viewbag' does not exist in the current context

What did I miss in my project?

Comment: How are you using it ? Are you getting a IDE warning or run time error?

Comment: Have you tried any of this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960148/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context