# How to resolve @ViewBag, HtmlHelper and Linq errors on compile with Visual Studio and MVC 5.2

Tags: c#, .net, linq, html-helper, viewbag

So I have this code and the screen shot displays the only 3 errors left out of 13.

[image]

I've updated VS and MVC to 5.2.

Here is the controller for ViewBag or where it exists in the code:

I need to find a solution for resolving this. I've scoured the web and Stackoverflow to see about fixing this issue but I cannot. I'm new to .NET and C# but as you've seen in previous threads, I'm more Typescipt and Angular 7 which, actually, helps me to understand the code structure. Funny how the code globally, is all coming back together, hmm?

So, if anyone has any thoughts or needs more info, please do not hesitate to ask and I'll gladly post more examples.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using Myprogram.Data.OpenSchema.Business;
    using Myprogram.Logic;
    using Myprogram.Logic.Interfaces.Emails;
    using Myprogram.Web.Models;
    using WebMatrix.WebData;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Myprogram.Web.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        public class AccountController : OpenSchemaController
        {
            // GET: /Investor/

            public AccountController(IEmailSender sender) : base(sender)
            {
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
            {   
                return View(new RegisterLoginModel(this){ ReturnURL = returnUrl});
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string ReturnUrl = "")
            {

                var isBorrowerAccount = SVDataContext.vw_MyprogramBorrowers.Where(br => br.DisplayID == userName).SingleOrDefault();
                if(isBorrowerAccount != null)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && WebSecurity.UserExists(userName))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin");
                    }

                }



                if (password == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bypass"] )
                {
                    CreateLoginCookie();
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);

                    var isBorrower = Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "borrower");
                    if (isBorrower)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("BorrowerDashboard", "Borrower");
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Investor");

                }

    #if DEBUG

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Investor");
    #endif

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && WebSecurity.UserExists(userName))
                {
                    var profile = GetProfileSchemaInstance(userName);

                    if (profile.Field("AllowFirstPassword").GetBooleanValue())
                    {
                        WebSecurity.ResetPassword(WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userName), password); 
                        profile.Field("AllowFirstPassword").SetBooleanValue(bool.FalseString);
                        OSDataContext.SubmitChanges();
                    }



                    if (WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, rememberMe)  )
                    {
                       CreateLoginCookie();
                        //Check if username belongs to borrower
                        var isBorrower = Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, "borrower");
                        if (isBorrower)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("BorrowerDashboard", "Borrower");
                        }


                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Investor");
                    }


                }

                ViewBag.LoginError = "Email or Password is incorrect, please try again.";
                ViewBag.UserName = userName;
                return View(new RegisterLoginModel(this) { ReturnURL = ReturnUrl });
            }
            public void CreateLoginCookie()
            {
                HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("logCookie");
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                loginCookie.Value = now.ToString();
                loginCookie.Expires = now.AddDays(1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
            }



            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
            {
                return View();
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string email)
            {
                ViewBag.Email = email;
                if (WebSecurity.UserExists(email))
                {
                    var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email);
                    SendEmail(email, EmailTemplates.PasswordResetEmail, new { ResetLink = Globals.SiteRoot + "/account/resetpassword?token=" + token }, subject: "Password Reset");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = String.Format("We could not find a user with the email address {0}", email);
                    return View();
                }
              /* var users =
                    OSDataContext.vw_SchemaFieldValues.Where(sfv => sfv.FieldValue.ToLower() == email && sfv.FieldID == 100); // field 100 is the Username field.
                if (users.Any())
                {

                }*/

                return View("ResetPassword");
            }
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult ResetPassword(string token)
            {
                ViewBag.ResetToken = token;
                return View("SetNewPassword");
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SetPassword(string token, string password, string password2)
            {
                ViewBag.ResetToken = token;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token) && password == password2)
                {
                    if (WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, password))
                    {
                        return View("PasswordResetSuccess");
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Error += "The passwords you've entered do not match.  Please try again.";
                }
                return View("SetNewPassword");

            }


            public ActionResult Logout()
            {
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                Session.Abandon();
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Register(string returnUrl, string confirmPassword, bool termsChecked = false, bool privacyChecked = false, bool isEntity=false)
            {
                // all the work is done right here
                var entities = MapPostValuesToInstances().ToList();

                var investorEntity = entities.First();
                // clear out any submitted entity names if the radio says no
                if (!isEntity)
                {
                    investorEntity.Field("EntityName").FieldValue = String.Empty;
                }
                // assign a salt
                investorEntity.Field("Salt").FieldValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                // custom validators will go here

               investorEntity
                        .Field("Password")
                        .AddCustomValidator(field => field.FieldValue.Length >= 8,
                                            "Password must be longer than 8 characters!");
               investorEntity.Field("Username").AddCustomValidator(field => !WebSecurity.UserExists(field.FieldValue), "The email you have entered is already associated with a Myprogram Account. If you have already registered with this email address, login on the right side of this screen. If you don't remember your password, please use the forgot password link.");
               investorEntity.Field("Username").AddCustomValidator(field =>
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           new MailAddress(field.FieldValue);

                           return true;
                       }
                       catch 
                       {

                           return false;
                       }
                   }, "Please enter a valid email address for your user name.");
                // if everything is valid, persist the changes and redirect
                if (entities.All(e => e.IsValid) && termsChecked && privacyChecked && investorEntity.Field("Password").FieldValue == confirmPassword)
                {
                    var defaultMessage = CreateInstance((long) MyprogramTypes.SchemaType.Message).Init(OSDataContext);
                    defaultMessage.Field("Subject").FieldValue = "Welcome";
                    defaultMessage.Field("Body").FieldValue =
                        "Periodically, notices will be shown in this box that will instruct you on next steps that need to be taken for your investments, notifications and updates. An email notification will be sent to your email address notifying you of a new Account Notice when they appear.";
                    defaultMessage.Field("Type").FieldValue =
                        defaultMessage.Field("Type").GetEnumValue("Account Notification").ToString();
                    defaultMessage.IDSchemaInstance = -88;

                    investorEntity.Field("Messages").AddNestedInstance(-88);

                    OSDataContext.SubmitChanges();

                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(investorEntity.Field("Username").FieldValue,
                                                     investorEntity.Field("Password").FieldValue,
                                                     new { investorEntity.IDSchemaInstance });

                    Roles.AddUserToRole(investorEntity.Field("Username").FieldValue, "investor");
                    WebSecurity.Login(investorEntity.Field("Username").FieldValue, investorEntity.Field("Password").FieldValue);

                    var test = SendEmail(investorEntity.Field("Username").FieldValue, EmailTemplates.WelcomeInvestorEmail, null,subject: "Welcome to Myprogram!");

                    // send the data to hubspot
                    //try
                    //{
                    //    var hsClient = new APIClient(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubSpotPortalID"]));
                    //    hsClient.Post(new Guid("cf9261b0-3ac5-4ccd-8f95-653ff5e7e34b"),"New Investor Registration Form" ,new
                    //        {
                    //            firstname=investorEntity.Field("FirstName").FieldValue,
                    //            lastname=investorEntity.Field("LastName").FieldValue,
                    //            email=investorEntity.Field("Username").FieldValue,
                    //            phone=investorEntity.Field("Phone").FieldValue,
                    //            state = investorEntity.Field("StateOfResidence").GetEnumString()
                    //        });
                    //}
                    //catch 
                    //{


                    //}


                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && returnUrl != "/")
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                        //return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Investor");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //return View("Dashboard");
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Investor");
                    }
                }

                // should be a more elegant way to do this
                var failedItems = GetFailedItemNameMessagePairs(entities, item =>
                    {
                        var overrides = new Dictionary<long, Dictionary<String, string>>
                            {
                                {1, new Dictionary<string, string>
                                    {
                                    //{"Username", "An Email Address is Required!"}, 
                                    //{"Password", "A Password is Required!"},
                                    {"Phone", "A Phone Number is Required!"},
                                    {"Salt", null}
                                }},

                            };
                        if (overrides.ContainsKey(item.IDSchema) && overrides[item.IDSchema].ContainsKey(item.FieldName))
                        {
                            return overrides[item.IDSchema][item.FieldName];
                        }
                        return item.ValidationMessage;
                    });

                if (!termsChecked)
                {
                    failedItems.Add("TermsChecked", "Please agree to the Terms of Use");
                }

                if (!privacyChecked)
                {
                    failedItems.Add("PrivacyChecked", "Please agree to the Privacy Policy");
                }

                // should this happen automatically in the base controller?
                foreach (var failedItem in failedItems)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(failedItem.Key, failedItem.Value);
                }

                // keep this pattern for now, data models shouldn't be directly exposed in the view render anyway
                // this gives us a tedious layer but should also help support "EDIT" functionality
                var entity = entities.Single(e => e.IDSchema == 1);
                var model = new RegisterLoginModel(this)
                    {
                        FirstName = entity.Field("FirstName").FieldValue,
                        LastName= entity.Field("LastName").FieldValue,
                        Email = entity.Field("Username").FieldValue,
                        StateOfResidence = long.Parse(entity.Field("StateOfResidence").FieldValue),
                        PhoneNumber = entity.Field("Phone").FieldValue,
                        Failed = failedItems,
                        ReturnURL = returnUrl,
                        TermsChecked = termsChecked,
                        PrivacyChecked = privacyChecked

                    };

                return View("Login", model);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Fantastic Suggestion...

Here's what worked.

Exit Visual Studio
Delete all non-project files (bin, obj. .vs, _ReSharper.Caches folders, *.suo files, ...)
Start VS and rebuild
That fixed it for me.

Then I got the 
webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" was incorrect and bin had 3.0.0.0

I changed the 2.0.0.0 to below and POOF!!!

The application lit up like a Christmas tree!!!

THANK YOU! <--- YOU SHOULD leave this because I mean it and I got the help from the int'l community when a local friend simply ignored me. This is what SO is all about.

```
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Razor view should start with imports of namespaces you're using. In this case that would be:
`@using System.Linq`

However, the `ViewBag` property and `HtmlHelper` extensions should be accessible by default. Which they don't seem to be. Which leads me to believe something is not configured properly.
As to how to fix that, this SO question might be of help:
[The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960148/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Cool, let me give that a try and I'll report back my success or failure.