# MVC3 Views unable to find added referenced class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reference

My view is having issues finding a class located in one of my references.
This reference is to a dll built outside of the project.

The view always gives error:

> The type or namespace name 'Company' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Here is the controller. No issues there.

```
using Company.Entities;

public ActionResult Find()
{
    Person test = Person.SelectByADDistinguishedName("L*", false);
    return View(test);
}
```

Here is the View.  The error occurs in the `@Model` line.

```
@model Company.Entities.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bob";
}

<h2>Find</h2>
```

My Views/Web.config currently looks like this

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Company.Entities" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I've checked similar threads like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-not-found) but to no avail.

Here is the message on the screen

> ```
> Line 25:     using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
> Line 26:     using System.Web.Routing;
> Line 27:     using Company.Entities;
> Line 28:     
> Line 29:     
>
>
> Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> ```
>
> Files\root\49c9c7db\1f9dd5c8\App_Web_find.cshtml.a8d08dba.xro6gxci.0.cs
>   Line: 27

If I strip out any mention of the assembly (out of web.config - no @using statments).  I get the same error message when loaded but against this line

```
public class _Page_Views_Home_Find_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Company.Entities.Person> {
```

Comment: did you try closing your view and reopening it? Or are you getting the yellow screen of death when browsing your view?

Comment: Compilation doesn't error out on syntax errors in views, are you sure the problem is in the view?

Comment: The error is still - CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dfait' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Added more info to the ticket

Comment: The compilation problem doesn't exist in the view -- to what section of code does the error refer?

Comment: When the view is open, the line @model Company.Entities.Person (Company is underlined) and the error show in the error list is the one i've mentionned above (the type or namespace name "Company" could not be found..

Comment: This still happens in vs 2012 + MVC 4. Solved by @Lareau's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After working it with it for awhile, I ended up solving it.

I had to add the assembly under the assemblies section of the main web.config (not the one under the views)

Sample of the web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="Company, Version=2.0.31.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df9010405db60e6d"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Thanks for people who gave me suggestions.

Comment: For some reason, even this doesn't work for me. It's driving me nuts that such a basic thing seems impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to check your views directory for an additional web.config file. I seem to remember running into a similar problem because I hadn't updated the correct web.config. YMMV.

Comment: Hi Hal, thanks for the quick response, I've added the content of my views/web.config.  I've added the namespace to both the views/web.config and /web.config but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the reference

before where you use your control, in .cshtml file works. Example:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyModel>
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

But you can put it in web.config, under namespaces tag. 
This way it is global to all views. Also, there is no need to specify the version:

```
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
</namespaces>
```