# Custom RazorViewEngine gives page error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to implement a custom view engine with Razor. The goal is if the view is in a sub folder to use that view instead.

I have my view engine derived from the RazorViewEngine

```
 public class RazorViewFactory : RazorViewEngine
{
public RazorViewFactory()
{
    string TenantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantID"];

    if (TenantID != null)
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new[] { 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" 
        };

        ViewLocationFormats = new[]{
            "~/Tenant/" + TenantID + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Tenant/" + TenantID + "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { 
            "~/Tenant/" + TenantID + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Tenant/" + TenantID + "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" 
        };
    }
}
```

}

and in my Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ...
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewFactory()); 
        }
```

Everything works except when I load my Tenant sub view Home page, I get the following error.

```
The view at '~/Tenant/TenantB/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' 
must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
```

If I load the base home page it works fine with the Razor engine.

Comment: Also, check out this post http://forums.asp.net/p/1595861/4048168.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to copy the `web.config` file from your `Views` folder into your `Tenant` folder (or make sure it has the same config sections as described here: [Razor HtmlHelper Extensions (or other namespaces for views) Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-not-found/4136773#4136773))

Comment: +1 Thank you. I hadn't even noticed there was a Web.config file there

Comment: thanks as i started the project as empty project and then add some MVC pages and using Nuget to add dlls so missed the web.config. This happened twice with me even then i dont learnt :)