# extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I've got this problem trying to use Html helpers. I've read that dynamical casting should work but I am not sure how to get it in my case. Code:

```
@{ 

 Html.LinkIfHasData(top.Text, Html.MenuTargetURL(top), false, 
 new { rel    = "tab" + @top.ID });

 }
```

LinkIfHasData returns MvcHtmlString and MenuTargetURL returns string.

I tried this:

```
@{ 

 (string)Html.LinkIfHasData(top.Text, (string)Html.MenuTargetURL(top), false, 
 new { rel    = "tab" + @top.ID });

 }
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thank you,

H

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-not-found

Comment: I was dynamically creating a bool that I used in foreach loop. So instead of doing var IsLocal = ... I did bool? IsLocal = ... and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inserted your helper within a code block, so the HTML generated will not go into your view.  Remove the helper from the code block, and put it in-line in your view.  Change your view as follows:

```
@Html.LinkIfHasData(top.Text, Html.MenuTargetURL(top), false, 
    new { rel    = "tab" + @top.ID })
```