# How to avoid using @using in every page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I would like know if there's any way to avoid using the keyword @using in every page to import some code.

An example: I would like to use `@Styles.Render("~/js/jquery-ui")` in some pages and I don't want to manually write `@using System.Web.Optimization`.

I saw in a blog that I can add a namespace in `<page>` in `web.config`, but I tried this but it doesn't work.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add it to the namespaces section of your `~/Views/web.config` (not `~/web.config`) file:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        ... add other namespaces that you want to be available in scope
            in all your Razor views
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I tried this:     <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization.Styles"/>
      </namespaces></pages> but it doesn't work.

Comment: This should work. Make sure you have reopened and closed the view in Visual Studio for changes to take effect. At runtime it will work. You can safely ignore the warnings that Visual Studio might be giving you.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the web.config in the *Views* folder, under the `system.web.webPages.razor` element.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization.Styles" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a global namespace in the web.config, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-not-found/4136773#4136773).