# Neither Views/Web.config or @using add MVC project's namespace to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, visual-studio-2012

I'm at wits' end here.

*Steps to reproduce at the bottom*

I've created an MVC 4 project, say `MyProj.Mvc`, in Visual Studio 2012 Update 3.

I followed the suggestion [here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) to put my `GlobalResources.resx` in a `Resources` folder under the project, so that it will compile into the DLL. I have looked at the generated code in `GlobalResources.resx.cs`, and everything is public. I can access the resources from other `.cs` files (e.g. `HomeController.cs`) just fine.

#### I cannot get the `MyProj.Mvc` namespace to be in the current context in any view.

For instance, in any Razor view, I can reference a resource like this just fine:

```
@MyProj.Mvc.Resources.GlobalResources.AppName
```

However, when I try to do the following:

```
@Resources.GlobalResources.AppName
```

I get an error. The `Resources` namespace is not found.

I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4136773/474683) and put the namespace in my ~/Views/Web.config:

```
<add namespace="MyProj.Mvc" />
```

And, the view still cannot recognize the `Resources` namespace. Rebuilding and/or restarting Visual Studio does not work.

"Ok," I think, "screw it, I'll just put a `@using` statement at the top of the page and deal with it later."

```
@using MyProj.Mvc // put at the top of the page
```

And, the view still cannot recognize the `Resources` namespace.

So please, help. Help! What could I possibly be doing wrong, that putting a `@using` statement at the top of the page *still doesn't bring the namespace into scope?*

#### Steps to reproduce:

I've been able to reproduce this with brand-new, clean projects. Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application called `MyProj.Mvc`. For the template, I'm mostly concerned with the Internet Application, though I've also reproduced this on my machine with the Empty project; select the Internet Application just to better match what I have. At the top of `_Layout.cshtml`, put `@using MyProj.Mvc`. Somewhere else on the page, begin typing `@Controllers.HomeController`. Note that the auto-complete doesn't even attempt to offer up the `Controllers` namespace, let alone the `HomeController`.

#### Now it gets weird:

So, that failed. Here's something, though. Try changing the `using` statement to `@using MyProj.Mvc.Controllers`. Now, go back and start typing `@HomeController`. IT WORKS!

### So, what makes the project's namespace so special, that it refuses to come into scope in the views???

Comment: Did you try moving the resource to App_GlobalResources folder? And then access it using @TestApp.App_GlobalResources.Resource1

Comment: The first link I gave suggested not using the App_GlobalResources folder since it would cause issues with unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how to access namespaces.

Just because you reference a namespace in your code it doesn't mean that you can directly access that namespace's namespaces.

For example, try this:

Make a new C# class called `MyDemoClass` like this:

```
using System.Web;

public class MyDemoClass
{
    Mail.MailMessage // can't do this
}
```

Notice that I know that `System.Web.Mail` is a namespace and I know I can access it. But just because I'm `using System.Web` doesn't mean that I can jump into my code and type `Mail.<etc>`. The compiler doesn't know what I want. Luckily it's smart enough to suggest

```
Do you mean:
    System.Net.Mail
    System.Web.Mail
```

That's why you can `using MyProj.Mvc.Controllers` and access your controller classes but you can't simply `using MyProj.Mvc` and then try to access the namespace `Controllers` from there. It doesn't work.

This is also why you see a lot of this:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Instead of this:

```
using System;
using Web;
using Mvc;
using Html;
```

It feels redundant, I know, but it's the way things are.

Try making sure the very last namespace is referenced. If `Resources` is a namespace then you'll need to `using` it or add it in the `Web.config`.

Comment: Then why can I access Resources.GlobalResources.AppName from HomeController?

At any rate, at least you've let me realize that I should just do what you said, and reference MyProj.Mvc.Resources in my ~/Views/Web.config and reference my strings that way. I could've sworn that I had seen it referenced as Resources.GlobalStrings.AppName (or equivalent) somewhere, but it's not worth wasting my time on it, especially if I'm trying to save keystrokes anyway.

Comment: What namespace did you use for your `GlobalResources.resx`? If you use `Resources.GlobalResources` you can access this automatically in Razor with `@Resources.GlobalResources` but not if you set the namespace to `MyProj.Mvc.Resources.GlobalResources`.

Comment: The latter, `MyProj.Mvc.Resources.GlobalResources`. Perhaps the examples I had seen had the resource class under the `Resources` namespace as you suggest. It's just weird that I can refer to it as `Resources.GlobalResources.<resource-name>` within the `HomeController` just fine. Perhaps it has something to do with it being a sibling namespace to the current scope (`HomeController` being under `MyProj.Mvc.Controllers`, sibling to `Myproj.Mvc.Resources`)? I suppose this would make sense, as Razor views probably aren't scoped within a namespace, so wouldn't have any sibling namespaces.