# Adding a View to a Webforms Website/MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an asp.net Webforms website that I'm trying to integrate MVC to. I'm almost there, but I'm having some problems.

**What I did so far:**

Added references to:

- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions
- System.Web.Mvc

Updated the root Web.config to load the three assemblies at run time.

Added directories:

- Views
- App_Code\Controllers

Updated the Global.asax and configured routing:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();       
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default",
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }           
            );
    }
```

So far so good.
I right-click the Controllers folder, add a "HomeController", like this, run the website and it works!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "This is my <b>default</b> action...";
    }
    public string Welcome()
    {
        return "This is the Welcome action method...";
    }    
}
```

Now the problem:

I update the HomeControler to use a View, like this, but it doesn't work.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }  
}
```

To create the view, I created a directory inside "Views" called "Home". Inside "Home" I added a new "Empty Page (Razor v3)", called "Index.cshtml":

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>View Template!</p>
```

The first problem is with this line:

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
```

VS indicates that *"The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context*

The second problem is that when I run the website, I get the following error message:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations
>   were searched: 
> ~Views/Home/Index.aspx 
> ~Views/Home/Index.ascx
>   
> ~Views/Shared/Index.aspx 
> ~Views/Shared/Index.ascx

I know it is possible to integrate a Webforms website with MVC pages.
It appears like my configuration is correct. I can successfully add a Controller and get the desired result.
BUT, how do I get my Controller to use a View?

Comment: There's some [config required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-or-other-namespaces-for-views-not-found/4136773#4136773)

Comment: @stuartd: already did that too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You don't mention, and your errors would indicate, that you did not install the Razor view packages

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: How to install them? Sorry, I'm new to MVC. I'm using VS 2013 Professional.