# View in an Area gives doesn't recognize 'ActionLink', 'Parital', 'ViewBag' even tho other areas work

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, view

This question is similar to the ff:
[Razor HtmlHelper Extensions (or other namespaces for views) Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-or-other-namespaces-for-views-not-found/4136773#4136773)

I already applied a sub web.config in that area and it can'tb be a nuget issue because there are already other areas that has the same structure but have their views work at it should.  Below is a representation of the areas:

```
Areas
--<Area1 - Folder>
----Views - Folder
------<View1 - Folder>
--------Shared - Folder
--------_ViewStart.cshtml
--------web.config
--<My Area - Folder>
----Views - Folder
------<View1 - Folder>
--------Shared - Folder
--------_ViewStart.cshtml
--------web.config
```

Please note that in the above example, Area 1 and its views already work and I simply added a new one.  As for the contents of the _Viewstart.cshtml, it only points to a file in the shared folder that consists of the general layout that is to be shared by all of the views in the area.

I am trying to figure this out otherwise I'd have to port every part of every page to a new View

Answer (score 0):

My colleague placed this on top of the page`@using KCC_MVC.Helpers` and it worked when we tried to build.  The funny thing was, it was grayed out (meaning it wasn't being used by the view). So I commented it out and it worked :D  It leads me to think its some sort of caching thing w/ the assemblies.  It's as if the IDE needs to be "reminded" of its visible assemblies.