# How to add namespace to razor view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Having to write

```
@using MyNameSpace
```

at the top of every view is a lot of work, is there a way to define it at one place and have the intellisense working for all the views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this SO question and first answer

[Razor Syntax @Using and Namespace Declarations fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/razor-syntax-using-and-namespace-declarations-fail)

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'll never be able to guess this one.