# Regex Replace function with Razor

Tags: c#, regex, razor

I was looking for a way to replace all special characters with a replace function. I want to use the Razor syntax but this

```
@Product.Name.Regex.Replace(@"[^A-Za-z0-9/\s/g]", "_")
```

does not do the trick.

I've tried this

```
@Regex.Replace(@Product.Name,@"[^A-Za-z0-9/\s/g]", "_")
```

and it failed as well.

By now I've tried a lot of other things and a lot of times I keep getting this error message:
"The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context"

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to add `@using System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of your template. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration) will help you if you want this namespace to be available in all templates.

Comment: Just to add to Raskolnikov's answer, when you know the correct name of the class but don't know its namespace, press CTRL + PERIOD and Visual Studio will suggest the "resolve" feature to import the correct namespace. But I don't think this works on the View, maybe just on the cs files.

Comment: It should work in the view, but I'm not entirely sure as I use Resharper which definitely does this. If you're not using that, I strongly recommend you give it a shot.

Answer (score 9):

To be complete, the right code for the regular expression is:

```
@Regex.Replace(@Product.Name,@"[^A-Za-z0-9\.\,_]", "_")
```

This will replace all special characters with an underscore.