# Combres, compress and combine .js and .css files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, combres

I'm trying to add the [following](http://combres.codeplex.com/) to my ASP.Net solution. I installed it using the nuget package "Install-Package Combres.Mvc"

so far I'm not having the best luck with it as I keep getting the following error

'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Combres' and no extension method 'Combres' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also followed the advice of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3876409/1105314)... and got same error:/

I'd like to make use of some compression & combination tool/framework so I'm hoping someone has any experience with this

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but Cassette (getcassette.net) has worked well for me so far.

Comment: I'll try it out quick. If/When it works, I'll let you know to add an answer so i can mark it as accepted :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I scrapped the whole combress/casette route after a few failed attempts. I read up a bit and saw that Asp.Net MVC 4 supports bundles/combining & compressing natievly. Which worked quite well for me.

Comment: This is true, but it does not do nearly as much as the Combres packages does. I am developing a large Mvc4 application now and the use of Combres over the bundling/combining built in gives me a lot more options. Combining and minifying are just a small subset, the use of css variables is a complete joy to have!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Combres" %>
```

On the top of the page to include the Combres namespace?

For more information (and the Razor syntax) you can also look at: http://combres.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=5-Minute%20Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Yes, i tried.  @using Combres / Combres.Mvc... no result for both

Comment: Is the assembly correctly registered using NuGet, or did you get any messages in NuGet when adding the package?

Comment: got no error messages, and as far as i can see in the configuration files its all there (i'm saying this without knowing what it "all" is though", but it installed without any hickups. 

as a side note I'm getting that error message in/out of run-time as well. The Combres Helper never gets picked up at all