# Extension method won't show in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, extension-methods

I've been following tutorials for this, and I've been trying to make this work for the past hour and i don't see where my mistake is so here you go:
I have a extention method in a project file:

```
namespace TomApps.Toolbox.MVC.Security
{
    public static class HtmlExtention
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString GenerateSecureDataControls<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
...
}}
```

I put in my webconfig:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/Home/Index"
                    mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="error" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        **<add namespace="TomApps.Toolbox.MVC.Security"/>**
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagPrefix="ext" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

yet, if i don't put

```
@using TomApps.Toolbox.MVC.Security
```

in my view, i cannot use it:

```
 @Html.GenerateSecureDataControls(model => model.RoleId)
```

At first i thought i I was because myname was conflicting, but i saw i made a mistake typing extension :) 
Any idea of what's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be under `<system.web.webPages.razor>`.. as below:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="TomApps.Toolbox.MVC.Security"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Jesus i suck... I've tried that but created conflicts, so it didn't work.... Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it wasn't working (or i didn't do it corretly). But i saw that i wasn't modifying the right webconfig, i was updating the root webconfig.. I added <add namespace> in the Views/Web.config and it worked right away.. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration)