# Strange automatic namespace imports in my Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Today I noticed that e.g. "System" and "System.Web.Security" are imported in all my razor views, although I did not actively import them. I checked:

- @using directive
- web.config (EDIT: also global web.config)
- AddGlobalImport

EDIT:

It seems these namespace imports are hardwired in the Razor Source Code

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/WebPageRazorHost.cs

```
    private WebPageRazorHost()
    {
        NamespaceImports.Add("System");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Collections.Generic");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.IO");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Linq");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Net");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web.Helpers");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web.Security");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web.UI");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web.WebPages");
        NamespaceImports.Add("System.Web.WebPages.Html");

        // ...
    }
```

It also seems that I can't disable these by setting a "clear" at the beginning of my web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage" >
        <namespaces>
            <clear />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

So this issue might be unfixable unless Razor source is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is: In Razor views some namespaces are always imported. This can't be disabled in configuration because it is hardwired in the code. These namespaces are:

- System
- System.Collections.Generic
- System.IO
- System.Linq
- System.Net
- System.Web
- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Security
- System.Web.UI
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Html

I am not 100% sure that this is the complete answer, but as long as there is no opposing comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

it is common , because it is registered in overall web config file at following location :

```
systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Web.config
```

it is registered like this :

```
 <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
                <add namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
                <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
                <add namespace="System.Linq" />
                <add namespace="System.Text" />
                <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
                <add namespace="System.Web" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.DynamicData" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />                    
                <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
            </namespaces>  
 </pages>
```

**EDIT:**

following is from an SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration):

*In Preview 1 Razor used the WebForms namespaces config section. However in the Beta there is a new config section that is seperate from the WebForms one. You will need to add the follwing to your web.config file (or just start with a brand new project from the template):*

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MyCustomHelpers" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this goes into the direction. However for Razor these settings are not in <system.web><pages>, but in <system.web.webPages.razor><pages>, which I don't find in the overall web.config.

Comment: True, but these imports still seem to be hardwired and I can't get rid of them by using this configuration section. See the EDIT to my question.

Answer (score 1):

*I ran across this question while answering another one ([Removing System.Web.UI from a Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244103/removing-system-web-ui-from-a-razor-view/18245352)). Below is a copy of my answer. It may be useful.*

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but I did a quick experiment. I think it works.

I extended the MvcWebRazorHostFactory a bit. The new factory basically passes along the host created by the base class, but removes the namespace first.

This is the class:

```
namespace TestCode
{
    using System.Web.WebPages.Razor;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Razor;

    public class CustomWebRazorHostFactory : MvcWebRazorHostFactory
    {
        public override WebPageRazorHost CreateHost(string virtualPath, string physicalPath)
        {
            WebPageRazorHost host = base.CreateHost(virtualPath, physicalPath);
            host.NamespaceImports.Remove("System.Web.UI");
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed web.config to use my factory instead of the standard one:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <!--<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
    <host factoryType="TestCode.CustomWebRazorHostFactory" />
```

Bingo!

Comment: this solution removes default imports but you can access it by typing long System.IO.File.Delete (X)