# Removing System.Web.UI from a Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The `System.Web.UI` namespace is imported by default in a Razor template.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Modify the T4 template that generates the Razor view.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's automatically imported even if the `using` sentence doesn't exist in the template itself

Comment: Well, the compiler removes it during compilation, so it's nothing more than an annoyance, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You could say so, even though I need to remove it for another purpose

Comment: What's your other purpose? If you tell us, then we may be able to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but I did a quick experiment. I think it works.

I extended the MvcWebRazorHostFactory a bit. The new factory basically passes along the host created by the base class, but removes the namespace first.

This is the class:

```
namespace TestCode
{
    using System.Web.WebPages.Razor;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Razor;

    public class CustomWebRazorHostFactory : MvcWebRazorHostFactory
    {
        public override WebPageRazorHost CreateHost(string virtualPath, string physicalPath)
        {
            WebPageRazorHost host = base.CreateHost(virtualPath, physicalPath);
            host.NamespaceImports.Remove("System.Web.UI");
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed web.config to use my factory instead of the standard one:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <!--<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
    <host factoryType="TestCode.CustomWebRazorHostFactory" />
```

Bingo!