# ASP.NET MVC 4 namespace issue in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces

I've added the following namespace to my Views web.config file:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html5" />
```

Now the issue is that in the Views, I can only use the types using the fullname:

```
@System.Web.Mvc.Html5.InputTypes.Html5TextBox()
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
@InputTypes.Html5TextBox()
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make sure you have added this namespace to the `~/Views/web.config` file and not to the standard `~/web.config` file:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html5" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Also make sure that after adding this namespace you have closed and reopened your Razor view in Visual Studio for the changes to have taken effect.

Comment: I can't believe it was as simple as closing and reopening the view.... Thanks ! (I wonder though why the view can't be refreshed automatically at compile time, whatever...)

Comment: Just spent 10 minutes wondering why it wasn't working - Close and reopen! "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"