# How to use class library in separate project within the same MVC4 solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm trying to access a couple of IsInteger/IsNumeric functions from a custom class library I wrote in a separate project but within the same MVC4 solution.

I have a class library called MyHelpers (class library project) and the other is called Portal (a web application project), so two separate projects in the same MVC4 solution.  After building MyHelpers successfully and putting the .dll in the Portal project's bin folder AND adding a reference to MyHelpers.dll, I still cannot find a reference to it in my Controller .cs file when adding the "using MyHelpers;" statement.

Why is this happening?  Am I missing something? I thought that if I add a reference to the .dll and use the "using" statement it will let me reference the functions in the class library.  What gives?

Please help and thanks much in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration

Comment: @Timmerz That's unrelated.

Comment: I would guess either your namespace is not MyHelpers, or the class is not located within that namespace, or...you have not instantiated the class so as to use its methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MVC4 project, add a reference to your MyHelpers project. This way when you build MyHelpers again, your MVC4 project will have the most updated build of the MyHelpers.dll in the bin directory. You should not simply just reference the dll directly unless you have changed your output directory to the MVC4 project's bin directory. Be sure to check your output directories and make sure that all necessary dlls are in the directory of your MVC4 application.

Comment: Thanks! I've had this problem many times before and this does the trick.

Comment: Same, project references make life so much easier.

Comment: while I agree with the project references here, he did mention referencing the dll directly, which should be the same, even if it is not the latest or the "correct" way to do it, which is why I think he is having another issue.