# Creating a custom countrydownlistfor - missing assemby reference on load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a custom html helper for an mvc5 application I am working on to create a dropdownlist for countries

```
  public static MvcHtmlString CountryDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, string css, bool displayPleaseSelect = true)
    {
        var countries = GetCountries();
        var list = countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = false,
            Text = c.Name,
            Value = c.Id
        }).ToList();
        if (displayPleaseSelect)
        {
            list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "- Please Select -", Value = "0" });
        }

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, list, new { @class = css });
    }
```

I think my helper looks ok however when adding it to an editor template view like

> @Html.CountryDropDownListFor(m=>m.CountryId,"")

I get an error

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'CountryDropDownListFor' and no extension method 'CountryDropDownListFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? The helper is in the same project

Comment: Have you imported the namespace in your view of the file containing your function? (`@using ...`)

Comment: Within the template if I type @Html. I get access to CountryDownListFor via  so I think its ok

Comment: Does the extension method lives in the same assembly? If not, are you sure it's built properly?

Comment: Sorry @Marthijn was correct. I think resharper was playing tricks. I added reference in the editortemplate and its ok now. Thank you

Comment: Glad you fixed it. If you do not want to use `@using` in each view, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration