# How to add using statement in mvc 5 to all views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

There are many examples of adding a using statement for all views in web.config for prior versions, but I have not found one for MVC 5.

Can someone give me an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add extra namespaces to Razor pages instead of @using declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration)

Comment: That answer shows adding a config section to the root config which is different from the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locate Web.config in the Views folder.

Find the namespace section.  It will already have namespaces for Mvc.

Add the desired namespace:

```xml
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
</namespaces>
```

Comment: How was it different from the other versions?

Comment: No example I could find said to put it in the Web.config file under Views, as opposed to the root Web.config.

Comment: @GregHollywood - most examples I can find do mention the views/web.config - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136703/razor-htmlhelper-extensions-or-other-namespaces-for-views-not-found/4136773#4136773 :)  They may not always be so clear on the location, but they do mention it

Comment: OK, well I tried several of those answer to no avail (missing the fact) and finally figured it out, so I thought I would call it out here for the next guy!

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET Core MVC you can also add inside `_ViewImports.cshtml` a statement such as this at the top if you needed to add the models class to your views.

```
@using Myprojectnamespace.Models
```

Comment: This appears to work in MVC 5 too. I added @Using inside one of my Views.