# @using by default in razor views MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, namespaces

I have separate Resources assembly and i want every razor view to have access to it.

Now i  put `@using Res = MyProject.Web.Resources;` in every view that needs it (later all pages will) and access the resources by

```
@Res.TheNeededResource.TheField
```

I tried to add the resouce namespace to web.config in view folder with no success

```
<add namespace="MyProject.Web.Resources" />
```

if i add full path namespace in view IDE highlights the namespace i've added in config  as redundant - when i remove it - error

How to add that namespace correctly? or some other way?

Comment: You may add the web.config section to your answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586619/5062791

Comment: Have you tried `<add namespace="Res=MyProject.Web.Resources" />` in the web config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382087/how-to-add-using-statement-in-mvc-5-to-all-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `web.config`, most likely the file in the `Views` folder, you can add a namespace with an alias like this:

```
<namespaces>
    ...
    <add namespace="Res=MyProject.Web.Resources" />
</namespaces>
```

Now you can call your code as you would before:

```
@Res.TheNeededResource.TheField
```

This is an undocumented feature of Razor and the IDE may render it as an error even though it is valid syntax. This means you may be better off changing the base page type to your own, like this:

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : BaseViewPage<object>
{
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public TheNeededResource Res => MyProject.Web.Resources.TheNeededResource
}
```

In your `web.config` change the base page type to your own:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyProject.Web.BaseViewPage">
```

Now in your views you can use the `Res` Property just like you use `Html`:

```
@Res.TheField
```