# v-bind error:v-bind' is an undeclared prefix

Tags: html, binding, web, vue.js, composite

I'm working in asp.net with Orckestra CMS (before Composite) and Razor Templates and trying to use Vue framework.

All is fine when using {{option.text}}

```
<select class="form-control" id="myExample1">
     <option v-for="option in options">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

But when I insert v-bind attribute, the page is broken:

```
<select class="form-control" id="myExample1">
     <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Rendering page fail and show **"Error: 'v-bind' is an undeclared prefix."**

Comment: I'm not experienced with ASP.net, but did you try to use shorter way for binding ? `:value="option.value"` ?

Comment: ASP.net? never use ASP.net

Comment: @BelminBedak i try also use shorter way and I have this:
Error: Name cannot begin with the ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A.

Comment: @EzequielFdeil Welcome to [so]! Note that the system already has a way to mark questions as solved, and does so when you *accept* an answer. (Thank you for doing so!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem is the XHTML validation, is very strict with tags, attributes, etc.

The way to sort this validation is inset the code between `< ![CDATA[ "blablabla" ]]>`

```
<select class="form-control" id="myExample1">
<![CDATA[     
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
  ]]>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's too late, but for those who searching, I found good solution [from here](https://rodney.id.au/posts/2017-06-01-vuejs-learnings/index.html):

> Well-formed XML cannot use the `:` and `@` shortcuts for `v-bind:` and
> `v-on:`. And in XML these attributes are interpreted as namespace names.
>
> To use the `v-bind:` and `v-on:` syntax in XML (e.g. XSLT files), add
> these as dummy namespaces in the XML, e.g.
>
> ```
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>  xmlns:v-bind="https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind"
>  xmlns:v-on="https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on">
> ```
>
> Then also add the dummy `xmlns:v-bind` to the `<html>` element of the
> output – otherwise the definitions will be repeated everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`v-bind` can bind without `:` like below:

```
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind="{value: option.value}">{{option.text}}</option>
```

is equals

```
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
```

cf. [Vue.js#v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem about vuejs as [this fiddle shows](https://jsfiddle.net/5ej6xfud/4/). The Razor Template engine does not know the namespace `v-bind:` and only `:` is invalid xml.
You need to tell the template engine about the namespaces of vuejs. Here is [another stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875207/how-to-add-extra-namespaces-to-razor-pages-instead-of-using-declaration) about adding custom namespaces to Razor template engine.

Comment: Thankyou for answer! Now, the cuestion is: Where I found the namespace of Vuejs? I need create this?

Comment: I linked another SO topic about this. I'm not pretty sure how to deal with the situation since i have never used ASP.net/that template engine.