# getting value of dropdownlist using vue.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, vue.js

I'm trying to get the value of a drop down list and change the div content using a get request 
 view

```
 <div class="row row-mb2" id="Produit-tab">
 @Html.DropDownList("Version", new SelectList(ViewBag.Versions, "IdVersion", "VersionProduit"), new { @id = "version" })
 </div>

<div id="versiondetails"></div>
```

script :

```
 $.Produit.settingsView = new Vue({
            el: '#Produit-tab',
            data:
                {
                version:''
                },
            watch: {
                version: function (versionprod) {
                    $.get("@Url.Action("Details", "VersionProduit", new {id = "_PARAM_" })".replace("_PARAM_", versionprod), function (data) {

                        $('#VersionDetails').html(data);
                    });
                }
            }//,.....rest of the code
```

I'm usually using vue.js with input using v-model="..."
but with razor i can't inject a vue.js attribut i tried this but it razor doesn't accept it

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Version", new SelectList(ViewBag.Versions, "IdVersion", "VersionProduit"), new { @id = "version" ,@v-Model="version" })
```

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/42029515/392102

Comment: No i can't use that , i need to use a viewbag  because the the items in dropdownlist  are not fixed

Comment: How about using `v_model` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/9444822/392102

Comment: oh i didn't know that using per with  ' - ' have to become ' _ ' in razor thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `@v_model` insted of @v-Model it will solve your problem.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Version", new SelectList(ViewBag.Versions, "IdVersion", "VersionProduit"), new { @id = "version" ,@v_model="version" })
```

Comment: please make use of the `code formatting` provided by SO. Select your code and press Ctrl + K to highlight it as such