# How to alias a type with a using directive in my Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, namespaces

I need to alias a type with a `using` directive, which is normally done like so:

```
using LocalResources = Resources.Admin.SomeResource;
```

How can I do this inside my Razor view so that I can then use it like `@LocalResources.FirstName`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is how

```
@using File = System.IO.File //at the top of the page then 
// use @File any where in the cshtml page.
```

Answer (score 4):

Razor does not currently support type or namespace aliasing. This is something that we might consider for future versions.

Comment: btw, does it support "using static" somehow?