# Import a Namespace in All Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

TO import a namespace, I know how to use the @using MyNamespace. Does anyone know how to globally import a namespace in all razor views?

I heard of a AddGlobalImport method, not sure how to use it though

Answer (score 6):

This link explains in detail how to achieve this.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jaishmathews/8652/

Simple add the namespace to your web config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="MvcApplication1.Utilities"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Comment: this needs to go into the web.config file under the **Views** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace in web.config under `namespaces` element. You already have some namespaces defined there. It is under `system.web/pages/namespaces`.

```
<add namespace="My.Custom.Namespace" />
```

Comment: like [Eonasdan said in the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7018805/edit) you should put this in the *Views* `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

As @Sparkle said, you can use the `web.config` file under *~/Views/* folder and/or *~/Areas/AreaName/Views/*. But, here is a total solution describes multiple situations:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723046/645167