# Issue with Html.TextBox (Helper) in codebehind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I compiled my Razor Views with MvcRazorClassGenerator and like here: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll
and in my view was source:

```
<h2>Hello!</h2>
<p>@Html.TextBox("hello", viewModel.foo)</p>
```

This tool generated .cs file with code:

```
WriteLiteral(" \r\n<h2>Hello!</h2>\r\n<p>");
Write(Html.TextBox("hello", viewModel.foo));
WriteLiteral("</p>");
```

But i have an error:

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'TextBox' and no extension method 'TextBox' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is it possible to use HtmlHelpers in .cs files like this?

Comment: “are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?”

Comment: Using directive in Razor is `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html`. Assembly reference has to be in your project. But I think it would be weird if that namespace wasn't included by default. Another possibility is [web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page/6723046#6723046).

Comment: Yeap, i just wanted to write it. Found here: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/Forum/openforum/OpenForum/Core/Views/Forum/Index.cs.htm. This tool didn't write all directives, and more of them u have to write urself. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a reference to the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html`. To add it, you can use `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html` to your Razor file. Or you could [add it to your web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page/6723046#6723046).