# MVC AjaxHelper Extension - The system cannot find it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

I am trying to build a AjaxHelper extension and seem to be running into a SNAFU.

View:

```
<%= Ajax.DeleteLink("Delete", "LicenseDelete", "Directory", new { LicenseID = license.ID }, new { @class = "directory button" }); %>
```

Extension:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DeleteLink<TModel>(this AjaxHelper<TModel> ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText
                                       , actionName
                                       , controllerName
                                       , routeValues
                                       , new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
                                                           HttpMethod = "DELETE",
                                                           OnSuccess = "function() { window.location.reload(); }" }
                                       , htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
}
```

Browser result:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper<RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC.ViewModels.DirectoryEdit>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'DeleteLink' and no extension method
>   'DeleteLink' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper<RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC.ViewModels.DirectoryEdit>'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What (obvious) thing did I miss?  I can swear the first argument in my extension method *does* accept pretty much any model I choose to throw at it.

TIA

-kb

Comment: Are they all in the same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely either need to register the namespace in web.config or in the view itself.

View example using WebForms:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC" %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx

View example using Razor View Engine w/ C#:

```
@using RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC
```

View example using Razor View Engine w/ VB.NET:

```
@Imports RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC
```

[How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)

Web.Config example:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <add assembly="RainWorx.FrameWorx.MVC" />
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx

Comment: I selected this answer as it was more complete and came in very shortly after Adam's answer.

Comment: NOTE:  I tried the web.config addition and it is not working.  I am back to the same error.  I even manually cycled all the app pools and such.  Sucky!!

Comment: Check the msdn link as you need to have the fully qualified assembly name correct in the web.config for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Include your extension namespace in your view. That's almost always the cause.