# MiniProfiler with mvc 3 and ef 4.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, mvc-mini-profiler

So i've just installed  miniprofiler.mvc to my web project and it seems to be working fine.
Except I cant figure out what to do to set up EF Code First and the docs seem to be outdated.

My project has a MyApp.DAL project where the EF stuff lives.

What do I need to do to start profiling EF? please help?

**UPDATE:**

I have installed MiniProfiler.EF 2.0.2 and now I get

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550046/using-mvc-mini-profiler-database-profiling-with-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492287/referencing-entityframework-4-1-namespace-in-mvc3-razor-view)`<system.web>`/`<compilation>`/`<assemblies>`/`<add assembly="EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />`

Comment: [Here's a little more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/215054/124069). Basically you're referencing the wrong assembly somewhere.

Comment: The thing is I have EF installed only in MyProject.DAL... I dont have or need reference to EF anywhere else in my code.... I use nuget to manage my libraries and it only displays EF 4.3 as a installed package :s .... dont understand why MiniProfiler is looking for EF 4.1 specifically.

Comment: maybe fire a like to this question over to @samsaffron on twitter.

Comment: so i've "fixed" it by simply adding EF to my Web Project... :s

Comment: I know but it seems kind of odd to me... I wanted to keep EF as separate as possible from my web project.... having to add that reference just for this seems absurd. there's gotta be a way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've "fixed" it by simply adding EF to my Web Project

This is not ideal but it will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure to install the EF package from Nuget?
http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF

> PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF