# What's the difference between page config section with and without pageBaseType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Razor for all my web pages. In my global web.config I have the following:

```
 <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

In my local (to view) web.configs I have:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyApp.WebUx.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="MyApp.Storage.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I want to make things as efficient and clean as possible so do I need to have the first of these or is just the razor section enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These namespaces are required if you are using any classes in your views from those assemblies. The are essentially global includes/using statements for each view that has the page base type of `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

If you remove them, you would manually have to import the assembly namespace. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page) on how.