# How do you implement a @using across all Views in Asp.Net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, namespaces

All I want to do is include this:

```
@using MyProject.WebUI.Properties
```

Across all my views without having to type it in each View, is there a way to do that in the ViewStart or Web.Config?  Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add your namespace to the views web.config under the namespaces element:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyProject.WebUI.Properties" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Note that you might have to close and reopen the view file that you want intellisense in for these changes to take affect.

Comment: @napspinksi make sure the web.config you are updating is the one in Views folder

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to get it included in intellisense?

Comment: @amurra (and naspinki) I had to close the view file and then re-open it for intellisense to pick up the new namespace.  (Visual Studio 2010)