# Cannot use NuGet PagedList ASP.NET MVC # View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I can't use the following namespace `PagedList` to use razor 
`@model PagedList.IPagedList<PhoneBook.Models.Contact>`in the topmost of view `Index.cshtml`

I already installed PagedList and i used already the code below in my Controller

```
 using PagedList;
```

there's no error in the controller page but why ican't use the namespace in Index.cshtml (View)? Please help..

Comment: you should put the assembly references in your `web.config` under the `Views` folder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3876409/365526

Comment: You can check my posted answer answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35433864/1148691)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

BuildStarted referral or existing on at the same time use,

in controller

```
using PagedList;
using PagedList.Mvc;
```

and use in view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<PhoneBook.Models.Contact>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

and use paging

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page =
page }))
```

Comment: When you added first time these usings on view, there might be error red underlines and you might not be able to use html helper of pagedlist. To use it, close the view and open it again.

Comment: Should I foreach them? Because now I can see the paging but I can't see the records.

Comment: I had to Rebuild before the view would acknowledge the references

Comment: FInally, after about 6 answers I've read at stackoverflow, this answer solved my issues quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I just found this question because I was having the same problem.  I have read through many tutorials suggesting the use of this PagedList object, but none of them said anything about adding anything to the web.config file.  This is what I did in order to make this work.  I used some of the info from the comment from @BuildStarted.  I am using VS2010.

Add this to the web.config file:

```
<add assembly="PagedList.Mvc" namespace="PagedList.Mvc" tagPrefix="plmvc"/>
```

So it should look like this (snipped):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages ...>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        **<add assembly="PagedList.Mvc" namespace="PagedList.Mvc" tagPrefix="plmvc"/>**
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nice. But also look at this answer. It helped me in VS2012 MVC4.5 - No idea why Nuget did not auto add it... I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, when I'm using @model

> PagedList.IPagedList

I get error :

> PagedList.IPagedList<> does not contain a definition for ....

Solution :

In View  -> Index.cshtml
 Replace model.Code   with model.First().Code

- Just Add First() before all properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had exactly the same problem. Visual Studio underlines PagedList in red and asks "are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?".

All I had to do was build the project. Then Visual Studio stops complaining.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add reference in your bin/assembly folder.

Comment: I had this same issue, I had to uninstall PagedList.Mvc and reinstall it because PagedList was in my references, but not PagedList.Mvc... Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a non-capitalised "M**vc**" in your imports and then rebuild.

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
//@using PagedList.MVC;
```