# The type or namespace name 'Repository' does not exist in the namespace 'MovieDatabase'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am developing an Asp.Net Mvc application with EF6 using below architecture

[image: Architecture]

I have also added dependency as follows

1) `MovieDatabase.Controller` (dependent on `MovieDatabase.Service` and `MovieDatabase.Repository`)

2) `MovieDatabase.Service` (dependent on `MovieDatabase.Repository`)

I after implementing Repository and Service layers, I created a view for registration

**Register.cshtml**

```
@model MovieDatabase.Repository.User

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>User</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileAlias, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileAlias, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileAlias, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAnonymous, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsAnonymous)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAnonymous, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastActivityDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastActivityDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastActivityDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordSalt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordSalt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordSalt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsApproved, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsApproved)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsApproved, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FK_Person, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FK_Person, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_Person, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**User.cs** (Model class auto-generated by `.edmx`)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MovieDatabase.Repository
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User()
        {
            this.UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
        }

        public long UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> FK_Person { get; set; }

        public virtual tblPerson tblPerson { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that, it compiles and builds without any error. But when I try to run it, it gives me below error

[image: Error]

I thought error might be because of "." between `MovieDatabase` and `Repository`, so I created another test project say `Chill` within the solution. But still I get below error

[image: Error]

P:S. I have already added all dependencies between the projects, that's why its compiling fine.

Comment: When you reference the MovieDatabase.Repository.User in the controller you're not getting compile errors? Since those are both in the same project, I'd expect that if one works, the other does as well.

Comment: @tlbignerd I have not got any compilation error in controllers. I can access MovieDatabase.Repository.User within the controllers.

Comment: I wonder if something got messed up in the project names. Have you see this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313308/namespace-not-found-in-mvc-3-razor-view