# MVC4 Areas Rendering Base _Layout Differently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an MVC4 application with two areas, "Reports" and "Admin".  I want views in these areas to use the same `_Layout` that is used throughout the entire application (`~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`).  When I build the application and hit it on my dev workstation, both areas render correctly.  However, when I publish it to Server 2008 R2 (running IIS 7.5), none of the views in the Admin area have the _Layout.  I've switched browsers, tried both on the web server and hitting it from another system in the domain, clearing the cache....nothing has worked.  Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a current project I have an area and in this area's `Views` folder there's a file called `_ViewStart.cshtml`. Its `Layout` property points to the application level `_Layout.cshtml` file that's within the `ApplicationName/Views/Shared` folder.

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Doing this you can share a common `_Layout.cshtml` file with all or only some of your Areas.

---

For more info about the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file be sure to check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9300466/114029

Comment: Neither area has a `_ViewStart`.  Are you saying I should add it?