# how to override a views Layout declaration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net MVC 3 is there a way to override the Layout declaration set in a view from a controller or action filter?

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I have tried overriding the MasterName property in the OnResultExecuted or the OnResultExecuting like the following code snippet, to no avail.

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
    view.MasterName = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an action filter to override Layout file, but if you want to remove it, you will have to create an empty layout file instead of assigning the Master property to null. Like this:

```
public class OverrideLayoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        view.MasterName = "_LayoutEmpty";
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OverrideLayoutFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now your new layout file needs to be placed in SharedFolder and you only put the RenderBody function inside

_LayoutEmpty.cshtml

```
@RenderBody()
```

Note: If you have sections defined in a view that you want to override layout you will also have to define those sections with an empty content.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it has to do with the fact that MVC does not know that the null value has been set "by the user" so it assumes that it needs to load the default Layout file. This is just a guess though.

Answer (score 4):

Another place where you can control the layout is in the `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

Here, you can do the logic you need and programatically specify which layout to use. This allows you to place the logic in only one place and keep it out of the view.

```
@{
    if(myBusinessRule)
    {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SecondaryLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

[Blog post where it was introduced by Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)

Comment: or `Layout = null;` if not layout is need it.

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewBag
when you need to change the layout call an action and put the new layout (even null) in viewbag.

```
@{
   Layout = ViewBag.layout;
}
```

and inside the action

```
if(something)
   ViewBag.layout = "~/Views/Shared/whatever.cshtml";
else
   ViewBag.layout = null;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to keep my layout declaration in the view, and just have a business rule determine when to switch it from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to simply add a ref to one of my previous posts on this subject, but have a look here, it may give a wider view (pun intended) on the topic:

[Where and how is the _ViewStart.cshtml layout file linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300410/where-and-how-is-the-viewstart-cshtml-layout-file-linked/9300466#9300466)