# How to change the Layout of ViewResult in ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm trying to create custom action filter that performs validation and based on the result it creates custom view. When the action filter is executed, it displays only the text: `<h2>My View</h2>` (No layout is used). I've also tried to override **OnResultExecuting** method and setup master name there **(filterContext.Result as ViewResult).MasterName = "Layout"**, but the result is still same. So is it possible to setup the Layout?

```
public class MyValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Layout { get; set; }

    public MyValidationFilterAttribute(string layout = "_Layout")
    {
        Layout = layout;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = TodoValidate();
        if (!result)
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { View = new MyView(), MasterName = Layout};

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }        
}

public class MyView : IView
{
    public void Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<h2>My View</h2>");
    }
}
```

// UPDATE 1:

Based on the ASP.NET MVC source code it looks like that **MasterName** is ignored when **View != null**. So I think If I want to use **IVIew** I can't reuse Layout, but I have to render the whole html page manually.

```
// ----------------
//ViewResult.cs
// ----------------

// FindView is called from ViewResultBase class only when the View == null
protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
{
  ViewEngineResult view = this.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(context, this.ViewName, this.MasterName);
  if (view.View != null)
    return view;
  // rest of the code
}

// ----------------
// ViewResultBase.cs
// ----------------
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
  if (context == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewName))
    this.ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
  ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = (ViewEngineResult) null;
  if (this.View == null)
  {
    viewEngineResult = this.FindView(context);
    this.View = viewEngineResult.View;
  }
  TextWriter output = context.HttpContext.Response.Output;
  this.View.Render(new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, output), output);
  if (viewEngineResult == null)
    return;
  viewEngineResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, this.View);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931722/how-to-override-a-views-layout-declaration

Comment: @Fran looks similar, but not helped. Even if I set MasterName to "whatever", it still displays just <h2> tag...