# Using the file _ViewStart.cshtml to something different than changing the site's layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been googling for a while trying to see the use of the file *_ViewStart.cshtml* but the only one I see is setting the layout to the views statically or dynamically

[image]

Can I use the file *_ViewStart.cshtml* to do something else?

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some understanding around the purpose of the ViewStart page:

[Where and how is the _ViewStart.cshtml layout file linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300410/where-and-how-is-the-viewstart-cshtml-layout-file-linked)

https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-layout-viewstart-renderbody-and-rendersection/

Comment: Reading the links I found the definite answer to my question here http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/10/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-view-start-files-for-razor-view-engine.aspx. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is used set the default layout for the website. This can be overridden in the view.

Additionally you could write logic to change the layout for some reason e.g. different layout for different devices.

You could also save data to the tempdata.