# What is _Viewstart in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Actually we can use layout in our cshtml page. Then what is the need of using _Layout path in _Viewstart page.

Can I write the code of _Layout in _Viewstart page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and how is the \_ViewStart.cshtml layout file linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300410/where-and-how-is-the-viewstart-cshtml-layout-file-linked)

Answer (score 14):

_Viewstart Page Introduced in ASP.NET MVC 3

The _ViewStart.cshtml page is a special view page containing the statement declaration to include the Layout page.

Instead of declaring the Layout page in every view page, we can use the _ViewStart page.

When a View Page Start is running, the “_ViewStart.cshtml” page will assign the Layout page for it.

and also provide more maintainability to our application.

**Note**: if we want to set views in a specific folder to use a different layout file then you can include another _viewStart.cshtml file in that specific folder.

Comment: @Rahan Sir: Do you have any link for easy understanding the filters in MVC.