# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' in .cshtm file

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am working on .cshtm pages and on the server side coding I am facing the exception
cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `string`. Code is below

```
@{
    var id = Request.QueryString["Id"]; //page.cshtml?id=5
    var data="";
    var query = "Select * from products where id="+id;
    data = db.Execute(query).toString();
}
```

string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I am facing this exception.

Comment: Is "id" an int or a string? And is it an int or a string in your database?

Comment: Have you tried using `string.Format(...)`? Ex: `var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id={0}", id);`

Comment: id should be a string it looks like then, the type needs to match the column type in the database.

Im just guessing that this is a database error then?

Also if your reading from a query string, it looks very much likely that your app is susceptible to SQL injection.  I know its another issue, but should be looked into..

Comment: You have `data` declared twice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is ripe with SQL injection possibilities.

You want to use `SqlCommand` and use `SqlParameter` to prevent injection.

This method you also don't have to worry about converting the types, ADO.Net handles it for you.

Assuming you are using the SqlConnection to connect to a MSSQL database:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
var query = "Select * from products where id=@id";
var data = "";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

    data = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to import System.Data.Sql and System.Data.SqlClient for SqlCommand to be found

Comment: Dear How can I import it in razor syntax on .cshtml page

Comment: Here's help with importing the namespace.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page

Answer (score 2):

If your variable id is of type `int`, you cannot add it to a `string` without converting to a string first: `id.ToString();`

Comment: redundant `Object.ToString()` call for value type =\

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the result of `db.Execute(query)` is an integer, try calling the `ToString` method:

```
db.Execute(query).ToString();
```

Comment: string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Now I am facing this problem to access the result.

Comment: Seems like a different issue altogether.  The word 'Name' isn't even in your code snippet.

Comment: Name is my database column name

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var query = "Select * from products where id="+id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Execute(string commandText, params Object[] args)
```

variable data is string but execute return int

```
var query = "Select * from products where id="+id;
int data = db.Execute(query);
//or string data = Convert.ToString(db.Execute(query), formatProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString()` to convert the integer to a string.

Personally, I prefer the following because it seems to provide more control:

```
var query = String.Format("Select * from products where id={0}", id);
```