# Higher order function in VB.NET (Select) gives me a "Select is not a member of [...]"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

I am a C# lover, and not very familiar with VB.NET. I am trying to do a classic:

```
var data = data.Select(c=>c.Id).ToList()
```

However, when I do this in VB.NET

```
<% rModel.SearchProductIds = Model.Products.[Select](Function(c) c.Id).ToList()%>
```

I get the following error:

```
"Select is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.List"
```

I don't understand why. My framework is .NET 3.5, so it should work.

Is it a syntax mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to

```
@Imports System.Linq
```

in your view.

Or perhaps more appropriately, add a property to your model that retrieves your product IDs instead of doing that right in the view.

If you use Linq a lot and don't want to add the `@Imports` statement repeatedly, follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723046/74757) to have it automatically imported to all of your views.

Comment: It is a web forms project (gone MVC-style as much as it can), and I have <%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %> . Still same problem. Hmmm :) Any ideas? Otherwise I will go the property way

Comment: Odd. That namespace comes from the `System.Core` assembly. What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting .NET 3.5 (I just rechecked)

Comment: Adding a property is the correct solution anyway, so i marked as answer