# ASP MVC 5 Html.EditorFor not working / Unable to access/use Default Editor Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

While attempting access/use the default editor templates in MVC5.

I receive the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'MvcContrib.UI.InputBuilder.Views.PropertyViewModel`1[System.Object]'.

**Why is this happening?**

Some background:

My model (TestModel.cs):

```cs
namespace MyTest.Web.Controllers.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public TestModel()
        {
            Name = "Fred";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My Controller (MyTestController.cs):

```cs
namespace MyTest.Web.Controllers
{
    public class MyTestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestModel testData = new TestModel();
            return View(testData);
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

My View (Index.cshtml):

```cs
@model MyTest.Web.Controllers.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyTest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
<div class="mainDisplay">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessResults", "MyTest", FormMethod.Post))
        { 
            <div style="display:block;">
                <div style="display:inline;">Name:</div>
                <div style="display:inline;">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</div>
            </div>
            <div style="display:block;">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The error occurs on the following line

> ```
> <div style="display:inline;">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)</div>
> ```

**and the view will not render**

Things I have tried:

- The sample from "[ASP.NET MVC Basics Part 1: View Model binding](http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/)" and this sample works without a problem.
- If I add a custom editor template under `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Name.cshtml` and I invoke `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name, "Name")` then the page renders
- If I change the code to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, "Name")` then the page renders

Finally, the solution has System.Web.Mvc assembly (which should contain the default editor templates).

**What am I missing?**

Comment: This works for me, though I had to remove the namespaces to get it to work easily in dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IcVwiv  My initial test would be to import your namespace into the razor web.config (~/Views/web.config).  See Javad's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page

Comment: Yes, I can see that the revised sample works.  It does confirm that  the code is reasonable.  However, that doesn't help answer why I am getting the error listed.  

Which namespace do you suggest importing?  The model namespace?  I ask because I am fully qualifying the namespace in the view when I specify the model

Comment: Yes, I would try the model one.

Comment: Sadly, that did not work.