# Access some session details in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a session in my Login Controller and there i send List of details via Session to the another page.So i need to take one item of the list to show in mvc view(Actially i need to show UserName in my mvc view).

My Controller

```
    public ActionResult Login(User usrdtl, string returnUrl) 
        {
//some code here
 List<UserDtl> usrList = newsManager.GetUserdetailsByuId(usrdtl.uId);
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UsrSession"] = usrList ;
        }
```

This usrList consist of lots of user details,i need to show UserName in my view.

In my view i tries to take it as,

```
<span>@Session["UsrSession"] </span>
```

But it shows me error

> > System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NTL.Sys.Entities.UserDtl]

How can i get this ?

Comment: Because its a list , you have to iterate the list to fetch the results. You can use LinQ or loops to achieve the same\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually does not show you error. It shows the object representation by calling `.ToString()` on the object.

In your case, `Session["UsrSession"].ToString()` returns `System.Collections.Generic.List1[NTL.Sys.Entities.UserDtl]`.

Your code actually has no problem at all, modify it to show exactly what you want to show.

I assume that the list contains exactly 1 item. To show the UserName, try:

```
<span>@((Session["UsrSession"] as List<UserDtl>).First().UserName) </span>
```

How to show the list is up to you, if you want to display a list of Users, just loop through it. The above code is just an example.

Comment: Then it also returns the List know.how to get the UserName from that list client side?

Comment: It shows me error "The Type or namespace name 'UserDtl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference ?"

Comment: @TechGuy: did you have a `using` statement in your view? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page. Try adding `using NTL.Sys.Entities;`

Comment: @TechGuy: there could be a mistake somewhere with your code. What if you try `Session["UsrSession"] as List<NTL.Sys.Entities.UserDtl>`

Comment: do it but it shows me the previous error "System.Collections.Generic.List`1NTL.Sys.Entities.UserDtl].First().UserName

Comment: @TechGuy: I'm not very familiar with Razor syntax. Try `<span>@((Session["UsrSession"] as List<UserDtl>).First().UserName) </span>`

Comment: I loop it through that list and do that.thanks for your help to understand the technique.

Comment: What you should be doing is `<span>@((Session["UsrSession"] as List<UserDtl>).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName) </span>`