# How fix Compiler Error Message: CS1061 in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using `ASP.net MVC 5` with `Razor Engine`. I want to create a page to register users . I create a Model and MetaData model for my User entity . All my codes are here . I think everything is Ok but I got this compile error :

`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'NP1.ViewModels.RegisterVM' does not contain a definition for 'UserEmail' and no extension method 'UserEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'NP1.ViewModels.RegisterVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Could anyone help me how fix it,please ?

**controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterVM vm = new RegisterVM();
        vm.UserAddress = "";
        vm.UserBirthDate = DateTime.Now;
        vm.UserCellPhone = "";
        vm.UserEmail = "";
        vm.UserFirstName = "";
        vm.UserGender = "";
        vm.UserID = 1;
        vm.UserImage = "";
        vm.UserLastName = "";
        vm.UserPassWord = "";
        vm.UserStatus = 1;
        vm.UserTell = "";
        return View(vm);
    }
```

**RegisterVM**

```
     public List<SocialNetwork> SocialNetworks { get; set; }
     public List<Footer> Footers { get; set; }
     public List<FooterMenu> FooterMenus { get; set; }
     public List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

**Register.cs**

```
    @model NP1.ViewModels.RegisterVM

    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Register";
     }

  @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
   {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserLastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLastName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassWord, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassWord)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserCellPhone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserCellPhone)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTell, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTell)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTell)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserImage, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserImage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserImage)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAddress, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAddress)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserStatus, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserStatus)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserStatus)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserBirthDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserBirthDate)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserGender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGender)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 }

  <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to using `YourNameSpace` in your `*.cshtml`. 
Like this：`@using MyNameSpace`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory.

Your razor view is strongly typed to `RegisterVM` , but it does not have a property called `UserEmail`.In your view you are trying to use the `UserEmail` property of your model.

So update your `RegisterVm` view model with the properties needed for the view.

```
public class RegisterVM
{
  public string UserName {set;get;}
  public string UserFirstName {set;get;}
  public string UserLastName {set;get;}
  //Add other properties needed for the view.
}
```

Or

Looks like `UserMetaData` class has all the properties you needed for your view. So change your model type class to `UserMetaData`. In that case, you need to change the visibility of this class to `public` from `internal`.

```
@model UserMetaData
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserEmail)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I know . `RegisterVm` is a ViewModel . I put User Model (with all properties ) in `RegisterVm` and I don't know why  I got this error. I think there is no reason for this error :/ .

Comment: Ideally you should add the missing properties to RegisterVm and use that.

Comment: I added properties to `RegisterVM` and now , I got `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error  for ` @foreach (var item in Model.Footers)...` .

Comment: excuse me , your second solution , I mean , change `internal` to `public` didn't break relation between `metaData` and `main model ` ?

Comment: Since you are accessing the Footers property , you should add that to the registervm and initialize that property in your get action method.  Try the first solution.

Comment: As you said , I added all properties . but I'm confused how I initialize  that , Could you please tell me a example ? , sorry

Comment: Looks like your view is not using any of those collection properties(Footers,SocialNetworks,FooterMenu etc..). You should remove those from your view model. Where are you getting the errors ?

Comment: No , I'm using those properties in Layout . when I remove Layout, Register page works correctly but I need those models in Layout. You said initialize that properties , I don't know how I do it because I'm new in mvc :( . I used ViewModels before and they worked correctly  I don't know why this didn't work.

Comment: You may initialize that in your class constructor to empty list. Also you may  need to load the real data (non-empty list) in your GET action. Take a look at this link http://bit.ly/1Ogo0ZI

Comment: Excuse me , you mean that I should change my `RegisterVM` to yours (your link)? I changed it , but I got same error :( . Really I don't want initialize properties with unappropriate data , I just want to create a Register page to add users and show some other links fetched from DB

Comment: So initialize it in your GET action method.

Comment: Excuse me again , you mean some codes like this : [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/20ef67d469b8adda35b5) , I did it but it gave me same error for Footer

Comment: I still don't you initializing the Footers collecction !

Comment: dear , with these codes ` this.Footers = new List<Footer>();
            this.FooterMenus = new List<FooterMenu>();
            this.SocialNetworks = new List<SocialNetwork>();` that error (null model) solved , but it shows empty footer.  I want to show real data fetched from db , could you plz help me again ?

Comment: You need to load the real footer collection in your get action. Now, I don't know your db structure or your data access code to tell you how to do that. What you need to do is writing some code to get a list of Footer item and assign that to your Footers property of the RegisterVm view model object.