# How is Html helper 'available' to all views in MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Perhaps this is a question for Programmers - I'm sure someone will advise me if so.

When using MVC, I can also access the Html Helper variable and use whatever extension methods are defined, either the .Net ones or ones I might have specified myself.

```
@Html.Raw("<h1>This is my HTML</h1>")
```

How is this achieved? Say I wanted to add a separate object for another reason and have it available to all views in my MVC app?

I know I can't add it to the controller, as one view might be accessed by several controllers.

So my best guess is needing to subclass IView?

Edit: sorry - I didn't explain myself. At least I think...

I want the object to be available, but also instantiated. So for example, say I had an object called `glosrob`, with a method `SayHello()` and wanted to be able use it thusly:

```
@glosrob.SayHello()
```

Essentially I want to avoid having to add code to construct the object on each view e.g. avoid this

```
@{
    var glosrob = new Glosrob();
}
```

Comment: How is the @Html.Raw achieved to be available in chtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How is Html helper 'available' to all views in MVC?

Inside your views folder you will find a separate web.config file.  In the config file will be the class that all views derive from:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

So all views derive from [WebViewPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage(v=vs.118).aspx) class which contains a property called Html that exposes the HtmlHelper.

> Say I wanted to add a separate object for another reason and have it available to all views in my MVC app?

If you want your own custom property exposed you should read up on [Changing Base Type Of A Razor View](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/).

First you create your own class with your own property:

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage {
  public Glosrob Glosrob { get; set; }

  public override void InitHelpers() {
    base.InitHelpers();
    Glosrob = new Glosrob ();
  }
}
```

And update your config:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyProject.Web.CustomWebViewPage">
```

Then you can call it in your view:

```
 @Glosrob.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your views folder you will find a separate web.config file. In this file you can declare namespaces that need to be imported. The section you're looking for is this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

If you want to import your own objects, you can add any namespace in this section and it will be available in your Razor views

EDIT: In case you need a specific instance for each view, you'll need to provide your own view implementation. You can do this by inheriting from WebViewPage:

```
public class MyViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    // implement property here
}

public class MyViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    // implement property here
}
```

Note that you need to provide an implementation for the generic AND non-generic version. After that you need to make sure that the View Engine uses this as the base page. In the section mentioned above you would do the following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="<the.name.space>.MyViewPage">
    ...
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

In case you can do with a shared object, you could define it in a static class and make that class available using the above method.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. However I think my question didn't quite convey my intention. Can you check my edit?

Comment: This is close to answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a couple of options.  You could put your Html Helper class in the System.Web.Mvc namespace like

```
    namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
```

You could also import the namespace on each page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication1.Helpers" %>
```

Or you could register in the web.config

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyHelper"/>

  </namespaces>
```

Also check this as a possible duplicate:
[Import Namespace for Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. However I think my question didn't quite convey my intention. Can you check my edit?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, the edit is much clearer.  @ErikPhilips is right as this answered a different interpretation of your original question.