# asp.net Html label helper weird behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the label helper in a web app:

```
@Html.Label("MyLabel", "MyLabelForAttribute")
```

according to the intellisense im using this function:

```
Public Function Label(labelText As String, labelFor As String) As System.Web.IHtmlString
```

Member of **System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper**

So the first value is the label's text and the second is the label's for attribute, so it should render this html:

```
<label for="MyLabelForAttribute">MyLabel</label>
```

However it is rending this html:

```
<label for="MyLabel">MyLabelForAttribute</label>
```

It is inverting the values.

I suspect the problem is that the web app (somehow) is using this function:

```
Public Shared Function Label(html As System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, expression As String, labelText As String) As System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString
```

Member of **System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions**

Is there a way to force the app to use this assembly **System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper**?

It is actually using the wrong assembly, is there a way to force the app to use **System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper** or fix the intellisense to show the used assembly (**System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions**) ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Do you have the latest updates? My VS2010 - VS2015 intellisense shows I am using the `<Extension>` method.

Comment: Take a look at this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-do-i-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page  It will tell you how set up using for Razor in your page/web.config.

Comment: @Jasen I'm using VS2015 (Professional) , the issue happens in VS2013(Ultimate) too. In a brand new project intellisense shows the     <Extension> method.

Comment: Then it sounds like your project has messed up the view page namespaces somehow.